# Subdomain CSS and JS File issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, .htaccess

I have the following line for my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index-merchant.php?id=%1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

What happen is if  I go in by

trytry.domain.com

It will use index-merchant.php?id=trytry

There this issue which is

My css stylesheet and js

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="canvas/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="canvas/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

This file is not working, when I click on them, it open the site itself again. How do I make my css and js work even after I did this subdomain htaccess

Another issue is

```
trytry.domain.com/category/helloworld
```

I want to modify my htaccess so it can capture both **trytry**(subdomain) and the query string **helloworld**

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood well
Try adding the base tag in your head section on every page you have

it should look like this

```
<base href="http://your_domain/">
```